Load data into Bootstrap modal
I'm trying to create a page where I load data (from a database) into a Bootstrap modal popup. The button to trigger the popup is in a repeater. I want it to open the popup, fetch some data, then possibly save back some other data when closing the popup.
I can't however get it to work where I get the data without the page posting back, which of course closes the popup. How would I go about doing this?
I've tried playing around with UseSubmitBehavior and CausesValidation, but there's something fundamental that I'm missing.

whenever you click on button there will be an postback, You can use UpdatePanel. or you can fetch data using AJAX.
